# Change GameObject Component on InitializeOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created script that i want to use as main script when my game launch. Now i want to access specific button text via that script and change it's text. I have problem because my text is not changing. Here is what i was trying:

```
static main()
{
    Debug.Log("Up and running");
    GameObject devButtonText = GameObject.Find("devButtonText");
    Text text = devButtonText.GetComponent<Text>();
    text.text = "Test";
}
```

Button is `devButton` and text is `devButtonText`

full script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


[InitializeOnLoad]
public class main : MonoBehaviour {


    static main()
    {
        Debug.Log("Up and running");
        GameObject devButton = GameObject.Find("devButton");
        Text text = devButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        text.text = "Test";
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: @NewCallum Still same, no respond :/

Comment: Are you sure the function is called ? Have you any error in the console ? (Check if the error button is checked in the `Console` tab)

Comment: @Hellium updated post, full script in now

Comment: In Unity the method called on start is called `Start()` : I feel like you're someone coming from C or C++ here (a friend of mine did the same mistake few months ago) ! ;)

Comment: Hmm, i think i misunderstood InitializeOnLoad, i had on mind to not attach script to any object, but to start at game launch. How can i do that?

Comment: @NewCallum : According to the doc : "Sometimes, it is useful to be able to run some editor script code in a project as soon as Unity launches without requiring action from the user. You can do this by applying the InitializeOnLoad attribute to a class which has a static constructor." - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html

Comment: Ah okay, only used unity a few times, I'll remove my incorrect comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created script that i want to use as main script when my game launch.

The `InitializeOnLoad` attribute must be used to run a function when the **Unity Editor starts**, not the game. Every editor script won't run when you compile your game. [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html)

> Sometimes, it is useful to be able to run some editor script code in a project as soon as Unity launches without requiring action from the user.

---

Instead, create an Empty GameObject and attach the following script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject devButton = GameObject.Find("devButton");
        Text text = devButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        text.text = "Test";
    }
}
```

Even better :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag & Drop the desired Text component here
    public Text TextToChange ;

    // Write the new content of the Text component
    public string NewText ;

    private void Awake()
    {
        TextToChange.text = NewText;
    }
}
```

The script will automatically be called when the scene starts.

Answer (score 1):

When Initializing a MonoBehaviour

1. You should use Start, Awake or OnEnable.
2. You shouldn't use constructor, static constructor or field initialization (like `public GameObject go = GameObject.Find("devButton");`)

This should work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class main : MonoBehaviour {


    void Awake () { 
        Debug.Log("Up and running");
        GameObject devButton = GameObject.Find("devButton");
        Text text = devButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        text.text = "Test";
    }
}
```

### Edit

Given the name **main** I guess this is the starting point of your project so if your script is not attached to any game object then Start, Awake or OnEnable would not be called. In this case you should attach it to a game object and **change the unity script execution order** and bring the script to the earliest point.

Comment: But my script is not attacked to any gameobject, i just want it to start running without any player interaction

Comment: I don't think that would work. You are basically trying to read a game object prior to execution of unity scripts pipeline so many things may not work at that point.

Comment: I added a note to my answer